# Site Health and PHP 8.1

Tags: php, constants

I just switched from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 and I noticed that in Site Health under WordPress Constants, both WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL show as Undefined. Shortcodes that use site url still appear to be working, so it doesn't appear that anything is actually undefined. But I would like to know if this is a generic issue with Site Health and PHP 8.1, or if it could be a sign of something configured wrong on my site. And if so, how might I go about looking for what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the constants `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are not required to be defined. These constants would overwrite the URLs in the Settings > General fields, so for most sites they are undefined.

Comment: Thanks @caleb, I guess I was confused about what those constants in site health actually meant. But I see what you mean. It makes sense now.